# Having trouble getting facebook sample to work - the one called "Feed Dialog".

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone have a working xcode project they could upload / share? 
I'm having trouble getting this to work clean without errors.

The example is located here.

[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/][1]

I have the project working to this extent -

The main viewcontroller is displayed with a button that allows the user to send a post to facebook.
When clicked, facebook indicates that the user has already authorized the app to post to their page.  He clicks OK on the facebook message and then the user sees the 'share' dialog and is allowed to enter text for his post.

As the sharedialog is presented to the user, I get this warning in my console

```
2012-09-29 11:04:25.190 gw_fakeapp[8016:fe03] FBConditionalLog: handleOpenURL should not be called once a session has closed
```

My problem comes when the user clicks "share", I get the error:

```
2012-09-29 11:04:32.217 gw_fakeapp[8016:fe03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.facebook.sdk:InvalidOperationException', reason: 'FBSession: an attempt was made reauthorize permissions on an unopened session'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14c9022 0xfe2cd6 0x14c8ee1 0x171d1 0x14367 0x3ad8 0x14cae99 0x14814e 0x386a0e 0x14cae99 0x14814e 0x1480e6 0x1eeade 0x1eefa7 0x1ee266 0x16d3c0 0x16d5e6 0x153dc4 0x147634 0x1da9ef5 0x149d195 0x1401ff2 0x14008da 0x13ffd84 0x13ffc9b 0x1da87d8 0x1da888a 0x145626 0x28ed 0x2815)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Does anyone have a working project I could compare mine with?

Thank you!

Phil

Comment: Hello Phil, did you get the solution for this? I also stuck on same point.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample of codes from developer.apple.com which describe about Facebook post publishing.

Here is the link: https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.pkg